# String suddenly turning null flutter

Tags: string, class, flutter, dart, null

I am trying to pass the text of a TextField from a Stateful Widget to a Variable inside another class called **firebaseController**. This works just fine, until I navigate to the second page with **Navigator.push()**. When i check the vaiable again, it is null, and not the String I entered. These are the two variables I have set up, setting the passwork does work, but not setting the email.

```
String email;
String password;
```

These are the functions I use to set the variables, and as I said, setting the passwork works just fine.

```
void setEmail(String _email) {
email = _email;
}

void setPassword(String _password) {
  password = _password;
}
```

I use the following code to set the email on the first screen and I have seen it being set, but when moving to the next screen, it goes back to null.

```
firebaseController.email = inputController.text;
navigateToPasswordScreen();
```

The navigateToPasswordScreen() function can be seen below.

```
void navigateToPasswordScreen() {
Navigator.push(
    context,
    PageTransition(
        child: PasswordScreen(), type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft));
}
```

I have already tried using the normal **MaterialPageRoute()**, that does not work either. I am setting the password in the exact same way, however that works. Below you can see the way I am importing the classes in my State:

```
class _PasswordScreenState extends State<PasswordScreen> {
    final FirebaseController firebaseController = FirebaseController();
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is because the FirebaseController object is different from object where you set the values for the variable.

Comment: Why aren't you passing the string as an argument to the second page?